# Loading... animating dots in python

Tags: python

This loading bar is really just for fun. I want to know other peoples ways of writing a loading bar that's considered animated like using time.sleep to give the "Loading effect". I know they're easier ways of writing it compared to mine, wanting to know how other people would code an animated loading bar?

```
import time
import sys
print('Loading')
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 6):

## Consistency

Sometimes, you use the [`print()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions#print) without a `file` argument and sometimes you use the [`write` method](https://docs.python.org/library/io#io.TextIOBase.write) of the [*text file*](https://docs.python.org/glossary#term-text-file) returned by [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys#sys.stdout). Those two are equivalent.

You should choose one style and stick with it. If you are editing some existing code, you should adapt your style to be the same as the existing code. If you are part of a team, you should adapt your style to match the rest of the team.

In general, if you use two different ways to write the exact same thing, the reader will think that you want to convey a message with that. So, you should only use two different ways of writing the same thing IFF you actually want to convey some extra information.

## PEP8 violations

The standard community coding style for the Python community is defined in [Python Enhancement Proposal 8 – *Style Guide for Python Code*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). You should *always* follow the guidelines of PEP8. There are plenty of tools available that can flag and even auto-correct violations of PEP8.

## More vertical whitespace

Your code is all bunched up together. Some [blank lines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines) would allow the code room to breathe, for example between the `import`s and the actual code.

```python
import time
import sys

print('Loading')
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And also to separate the two steps of printing the header "Loading" and printing the animation:

```python
import time
import sys

print('Loading')

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

## Less vertical whitespace.

Your code ends with two blank lines. There should be no blank lines at the end of the file. [A file should end with a single newline character after the last non-whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/2988).

Note: the section on Blank Lines in PEP8 says [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ***Surround*** top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

which seems to imply that, if the last element of your file is a top-level function or a top-level class, there should be two blank lines after it, but I believe this is a mistake in PEP8. In my humble opinion, it should read:

> ***Separate*** top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

Anyway, you have neither top-level functions nor top-level classes in your code, therefore, this is a moot point.

```python
import time
import sys

print('Loading')

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

## Naming

Unused variables should be named `_`. You are not using the variable `i`, so it should be named `_` instead.

```python
import time
import sys

print('Loading')

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

## Comments

Generally speaking, comments are a [*code smell*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html). Mostly, comments should not exist:

- If your code is so complex that you need to explain it in a comment, you should rather try to refactor your code to be less complex.
- If you have a comment that explains what something is, you can rather give it a name.
- If you have a comment that explains how the code does something, just delete it: the code explains how the code does something.

The only acceptable thing for a comment is to explain *why* the code does something in a specific non-obvious way. So, for example, there is an obvious way that looks like it *should* work, but you tried it and it didn't work for a non-obvious reason. Then you can add a comment explaining that you are specifically using solution B even though it looks like much simpler solution A should also work, but it actually doesn't work because of issue X. Ideally, you would add a link to the pull request / code review / bug ticket where this issue is discussed in greater detail and maybe a link to a wiki page with a detailed explanation.

In your code, you have no comments, which is reasonable: the code is straightforward and simple, there is nothing to explain.

## Documentation

Your code has no documentation. Every public module, class, function, method, etc. should have a [docstring](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#documentation-strings).

Your code is implicitly a public module, so it should have a docstring.

## Linter, style checker, static analyzer, code formatter

You should use a linter and/or a static analyzer, preferably one with an auto-correct functionality. I actually have multiple linters and multiple static analyzers configured in my editor, and they are set up so that they analyze my code while I type, and automatically correct whatever they can auto-correct when I save.

Here are some of the ones I use:

- [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)
- [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright)
- [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/)
- [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/)
- [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [Yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf)
- [Bandit](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/)
- [mccabe](https://pypi.org/project/mccabe/)
- [Prospector](https://prospector.landscape.io/en/master/)
- [Pycodestyle](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/)
- [Pydocstyle](https://pydocstyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/)
- [Pyflakes](https://pypi.org/project/pyflakes)
- [Radon](https://radon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [eradicate](https://pypi.org/project/eradicate/)
- [Vulture](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture)
- [Pylama](https://github.com/klen/pylama)
- [Pylint](https://pylint.org/)

Using these tools frees you from a lot of the responsibilities for the minutiae of writing the code: whitespace, indentation, formatting, simple bugs, best practices, etc. The tools do a lot of the work for you, and in cases where they can't do the work themselves, they at least give you good, readable warnings with actionable information that tells you what to do.

In short: you can focus your brain on *solving the problem* and leave the low-level concerns of *coding* to the tools.

For example, all of the things I mention above, are automatically taken care of for me, if I simply copy&paste your code into my text editor. It automatically inserts the blank line after the `import`s and removes the blank lines at the end. (It also converts all string literals to double quotes, but that's just a setting that can be changed.)

## Missing newline

Just like the source code file itself, the text you print to the console should end with a single newline. Otherwise, all *further* code that is printed to the console by your program, will end up bunched up after the last `.` instead of at the beginning of the next line. Or, if the animation is the last thing your code prints, then the shell prompt might appear directly after the `.` instead of at the beginning of the next line.

```python
import time
import sys

print('Loading')

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

print()
```

## `print` vs. `sys.stdout.write`

`print` has a `file` parameter which tells `print` which file to print to. If you don't pass a `file` argument, the default is to print to `sys.stdout`. In other words: using `print` or `sys.stdout.write` are equivalent. You could make your code more consistent and reduce the number of `import`s by only using `print`:

```python
import time

print('Loading')

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('.', end='', flush=True)

print()
```

## Magic values

There are a couple of [*magic values*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code that could use some explanation. You *could* add comments to explain those values, but remember what we said about comments above: ideally, the code should explain itself with no need for comments.

So, instead of writing comments to explain those values, we can assign them to variables with intention-revealing names:

```python
import time

title = 'Loading'
iterations = 3
seconds_between_iterations = 0.5
character = '.'

print(title)

for _ in range(iterations):
    time.sleep(seconds_between_iterations)
    print(character, end='', flush=True)

print()
```

See, for example, how the name `seconds_between_iterations` leaves no question about what unit the `0.5` is in, even if you don't know [the definition of `time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/library/time#time.sleep) by heart: it's half a second.

If we *really* decide that we *absolutely need* comments here, we now have some named entity in the source code that we can attach a documentation comment to: the variables.

```python
import time

title = 'Loading'
"""The title to print before the animation."""

iterations = 3
"""The number of iterations of the loop."""

seconds_between_iterations = 0.5
"""The number of seconds to wait between printing characters."""

character = '.'
"""The character to print."""

print(title)

for _ in range(iterations):
    time.sleep(seconds_between_iterations)
    print(character, end='', flush=True)

print()
```

Since we now have proper docstrings which are attached to the variables, they will be displayed when you hover over the variable:

[image: Documentation string for a variable shown while hovering over the variable]

Another advantage of having these variables as named entities in our source code, is that we can give them *type annotations*. In this case, you can see that Pyright has automatically inferred the type `Literal['.']` for the variable, which is the most restrictive type you can have. But you might want to provide a different type, which you can now do, because there is something you can attach the type to: the variable.

## Reusability: subroutines

Your code is not very reusable. It would be much better to wrap it into a function, so you can use it in multiple places:

```python
import time


def print_loader_animation() -> None:
    title = 'Loading'
    """The title to print before the animation."""

    iterations = 3
    """The number of iterations of the loop."""

    seconds_between_iterations = 0.5
    """The number of seconds to wait between printing characters."""

    character = '.'
    """The character to print."""

    print(title)

    for _ in range(iterations):
        time.sleep(seconds_between_iterations)
        print(character, end='', flush=True)

    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_loader_animation()
```

## More reusability: parameters

At the moment, we have a function which we can call multiple times, so we can reuse the function in multiple places. However, if we want to use if for, say, a *saving* animation, that is not possible, because it always prints `Loading`.

To solve that, we can introduce *parameters*. In fact, we have already identified all the things you might want to parameterize and given them names.

```python
"""Print a waiting animation to the console."""

import time


def print_waiting_animation(
    *,
    title: str,
    iterations: int = 3,
    seconds_between_iterations: float = 0.5,
    character: str = '.'
) -> None:
    """
    Print a waiting animation to the console.

    :param title: The title to print before the animation.
    :param iterations: The number of iterations of the loop.
    :param seconds_between_iterations: The number of seconds to wait between
        printing characters.
    :param character: The character to print.
    """
    print(title)

    for _ in range(iterations):
        time.sleep(seconds_between_iterations)
        print(character, end='', flush=True)

    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_waiting_animation(title='Loading')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `class` which allows consumers to specify the following:

- The character to be written.
- The number of characters to be written.
- The delay before writing each character.

For example:

```
import time
import sys

class Loader:
  def __init__(self, displayCharacter, count, delay):
    self.displayCharacter = displayCharacter
    self.count = count
    self.delay = delay
  def start(self):
      sys.stdout.write('Loading')
      for i in range(self.count):
          time.sleep(self.delay)
          sys.stdout.write(self.displayCharacter)
          sys.stdout.flush()
          
loader = Loader('', 5, 0.5)
loader.start()
```

In my opinion, the next logical step is to create a way to prematurely stop the loader. However, I'll leave that to you, dear reader.

---

‍♀️ Note, I come from the C# world and have almost no Python experience. However, given the fact that Python is an object-oriented language, creating a class to promote reuse should become second nature.

Comment: This is so cool thank you for sharing!

Comment: Your code is very un-Pythonic. Firstly, it contains multiple violations of PEP8. Secondly, an object is overkill here, a function would do just fine. Thirdly, the positional parameters are confusing, named parameters would be more self-explanatory. Fourth, there is no documentation, there should be a docstring for every public module, public class, and public method. Fifth, modern Python uses type annotations quite heavily.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Perhaps it's better to give your feedback in a manner that doesn't come across as "your code is wrong" and instead conveys the shortcomings as points that future readers should be aware of. I noted in my answer that I have almost no Python experience and that the example was given to demonstrate how the functionality could be encapsulated for reuse which should become second nature to developers in an object-oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a common answer as well. Just written shorter but I dont think it looks as organized as the code above when it prints.

```
import time
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('.',end= ' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].